# Error Conexion spring boot con base de datos db2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, db2

Buenas tardes amigos estoy tratando de conectar una aplicacion spring boot con db2 pero recibo un error que es el siguiente:

```
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:241) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientException: [jcc][t4][2034][11148][4.13.127] Execution failed due to a distribution protocol error that caused deallocation of the conversation.
A DRDA Data Stream Syntax Error was detected.  Reason: 0x0. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=58009
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:322) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:366) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.j(z.java:967) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.bb(ab.java:2145) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.y(ab.java:774) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.n(ab.java:673) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:474) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:117) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.m(b.java:1334) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:1205) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:786) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(b.java:758) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:421) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:396) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:334) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:231) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:197) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:472) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:113) ~[db2jcc4-10.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

mi archivo application.properties:

```js
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://10.14.15.72/SALUD?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=1234
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
#spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
#spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.mvc.contentnegotiation.favor-parameter=true
spring.mvc.contentnegotiation.media-types.pdf = application/pdf
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
```

y mi archivo pom se ve asi:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.kalettre.rest</groupId>
 <artifactId>Rest</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>Rest</name>
 <description></description>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-snapshots</id>
   <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-milestones</id>
   <name>Spring Milestones</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>

  <repository>
   <id>com.ibm.db2.jcc</id>
   <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
  </repository>

 </repositories>


 <dependencies>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
   <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
   <version>10.1</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
   <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.5</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
   <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
   <version>9.1.7</version>
  </dependency>






 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

 <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>spring-snapshots</id>
   <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>spring-milestones</id>
   <name>Spring Milestones</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

Comment: Ya probaste alguna de estas soluciones? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21691531 Al parecer es un error de `db2` más que de spring.

Answer (score 0):

El código de error de IBM Db2 es el SQL4499 y viendo el archivo de configuración de spring, dice que el dialecto de Hibernate es MySQL. Probablemente es eso.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```